Limiting Access to logs on a specific cluster to Grafana Admins
I have 3 cluster (A-B-C), I installed loki on cluster A using the grafana/loki helm chart, and on cluster B and C I have promtail installed pushing logs to cluster A, how can I make logs collected from cluster A only displayable to Grafana Admins.
Labeling logs source only allows to setup restrictions on dashboard level, how can I can make it so that the logs of cluster A are not even accessible from the datasource level ?
